# How to know if logreader agent already exists?

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a script to recreate a database for test purposes, and the database has some publications.  In order to create or not the logreader agent I need to know if the current database already has one, or destroy the existing agent prior to recreate the database. I know there is some class in SMO can do that, but I need to achieve the same with T-SQL.  Someone can help?

Comment: I'm not currently by a test box, but if you can do this with SMO then just reverse engineer the SQL to accomplish this by using XEvents or creating a SQL Trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below T-SQL will give you the log reader agent. You can use the agent name or job_id to drop/delete the log reader agent.

```
    SELECT SERVER
    ,[command]
    ,sj.job_id
    ,[NAME]
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON sjs.job_id = sj.job_id
    AND subsystem = 'logreader'
```

Comment: This works in the case of the distributor being on the same SQL instance as the publisher - but is there a way to do this if the we are executing on a remote publisher?